# Spring web-scoped beans and axis2

Tags: web-services, spring, integration, apache-axis, web.xml

I want to use spring web-scoped beans in web-service written on AXIS2 framework. 
How to configure it?
Axis2 and Spring documentation disagree with each other.

[Axis2 documentation says](http://axis.apache.org/axis2/java/core/docs/spring.html#a23):

> ```
> For the purpose of this example, we'll configure Spring via a WAR file's web.xml. Let's add a context-param and a listener:
> ```

```
<listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>
<context-param>
      <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
      <param-value>/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
```

[Spring documentation says](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/reference/beans.html#beans-factory-scopes-other-web-configuration):

> ```
> When using a Servlet 2.4+ web container, with requests processed outside of Spring's DispatcherServlet (e.g. when using JSF or Struts), you need to add the following javax.servlet.ServletRequestListener to the declarations in your web application's 'web.xml' file.
> ```

```
<web-app>
  ...
  <listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener</listener-class>
  </listener>
  ...
</web-app>
```

When I use Axis2-recommended ContextLoaderListener with Spring web-scoped beans I got on deploy

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: No thread-bound request found: Are
>   you referring to request attributes outside of an actual web request,
>   or processing a request outside of the originally receiving thread? If
>   you are actually operating within a web request and still receive this
>   message, your code is probably running outside of
>   DispatcherServlet/DispatcherPortlet: In this case, use
>   RequestContextListener or RequestContextFilter to expose the current
>   request.

When I use Spring-recommeded RequestContextListener I got running Web-service with fault on requests:

```
        <faultstring>The SERVICE_OBJECT_SUPPLIER parameter is not specified.</faultstring>
```

In other words: how to configure AXIS2 with Spring and RequestContextListener?

Comment: Also started discussion here: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/AXIS2-5467

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No such functionality in AXIS2. See request https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/AXIS2-5467  "Extend Spring support to accept web-scoped beans" for detail.